# Route network traffic through VPN in ios without manual configuration

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, networking, vpn

what is the best approach to route all the network traffic through a secure VPN server on IOS device. This configuration should not be something which the user should be able to modify. It is more of like forcing my employees to use my company's VPN server even if they are connected to any wifi hotspot. The user should not be able to disable this setting.

Comment: what if the user doesnt have VPN configured in his device ?

Comment: I am thinking of connecting to my default server everytime. Can the server configuration be hard wired in my application ?

Comment: This configuration should be like a push message. When the user logs in to my company wifi network. It should be automatically installed